# Python close all threads or processes with subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I work on a simple gui application.

In my real case, this application starts Django (**python manage.py runserver**) webserver and close Django webserver. In order to, simplify the testability of my app, I replace django start webserver by **sleep** command.

When I fire **Start server** button : the server starts.
Then, I fire **Stop server** button, and the process closes.

But the django webserver (or sleep command) is still working.

How can I stop the process AND stop de command called by **subprocess.Popen** ?

There is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding:utf-8
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time
import datetime
import zipfile
import subprocess
from concurrent import futures
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

def runserver():
    cmd = 'sleep 60'
    # os.system(cmd)
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
    print('TERMINATE BY TIMEOUT')
    return True

class WindowMain:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.thread_srv = None
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)

        self.lbl = tk.Label(text="")
        self.lbl.pack()

        self.btn_quit = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Stop server", width=25, command=lambda:  self.stop_server())
        self.btn_quit.pack()

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text="Start Server", width=25, command=lambda: self.runserver_thread())
        self.button1.pack()

        self.frame.pack()

    def stop_server(self):
        if self.thread_srv:
            print('THREAD')
            self.thread_srv.terminate()
        else:
            print("NOT THREAD")

    def runserver_thread(self):
        self.thread_srv = Process(target=runserver)
        self.thread_srv.start()

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def quit(root):
    root.quit
    sys.exit()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    tk.Button(root, text="Quitter", command=lambda: quit(root)).pack()
    app = WindowMain(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Solution (after ForceBru's answer)

I code this function which close django server :

```
def close_django_runserver():
    if 'win' in sys.platform:
        pass
    else:
        cmd = 'ps aux'
        output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
        process_list = output.split("\n")
        for process in process_list:
            if 'manage.py' in process and 'runserver' in process:
                pid = re.sub(r'^[^\s]+\s+(\d+)\s+.*$', r'\1', process)
                subprocess.Popen('kill '+str(pid), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```

It certainly exists a better solution, bu it works. I will code Windows solution at a later time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run the Django start script, everything gets initialized and set up and then that newly created Django process goes to background (gets * daemonized*) *disconnected from your thread*.

So, when you kill that thread, you actually kill nothing because that start-up script has done its job and has probably already exited.

After the start-up script is run, a *new Django process is created*. Experiment on your machine and find its name. Then you can run something like `sudo killall django_process` from within your program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is there a way to close the django server from my script ?

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.